# Most readable and efficient way to check if an item exists inside of array in an if statement even if item is 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Given the following array of arrays of numbers

```
numbers = [[7, 4, 0, 1], // see 0 at position [0][2]
           [5, 6, 2, 2], 
           [6, 9, 7, 8], 
           [1, 4, 2, 0]]
```

I'd like to check if a number exists in inner array `array[j]` and a `array[j+2]`. `array[j]` and `array[j+2]` could be `0` at times. In an if statement like the below, I'm having problems due to `0` being a falsy value.

```
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
    if (numbers[i][j] && numbers[i][j+2]) {
      // how to evaluate this to true even if numbers[i][j] or numbers[i][j+2] is the number 0?
     }
  }
}
```

I tried adding an extra `||` check to see if that number was `0`, e.g. `(numbers[i][j] || numbers[i][j] === 0) && (numbers[i][j+2] || numbers[i][j+2] === 0)` which I think looks terrible.

Comment: `numbers.flat().includes(n)`?

Answer (score 1):

If the array entry is not present, JavaScript will return `undefined`. Therefore, the following code should work:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
    if (numbers[i][j] !== undefined && numbers[i][j+2] !== undefined) {
      // how to evaluate this to true even if numbers[i][j] or numbers[i][j+2] is the number 0?
     }
  }
}
```